# ObservableCollection<T> replace and how to get DataModel to fire property changed

Tags: c#, wpf

So everything works great apart from one part of my code. I'm going through an observable collection and a list and I am setting an element in the observable collection equal to an element from the list

```
someitemInOC = newListItem;
```

Now, the CollectionChanged event gets triggered, but the problem is I also want all properties of the type of `someitemInOC` to also get triggered... because I have a `SomeType_PropertyChanged` function I'd like to have called............ problem is I don't know how this can be done. Obviously the type of `someitemInOC` has all its properties with the `OnNotifyPropertyChanged` function in the setter... but how can I trigger all properties to get their notify called? This is a datamodel, not a viewmodel, but nonetheless it does inherit INotifyPropertyChanged

A snippet of my DataModel

```
public sealed class WModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isD;
    public bool IsD
    {
        get { return isD; }
        set { isD = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private string wd;
    public string Wd
    {
        get { return wd; }
        set { wd = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public void UpdateAllParameters()
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged(string.Empty);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

In my VM constructor I have

```
WSource.CollectionChanged += WSource_CollectionChanged;
```

and then further down

```
    private void WSource_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            foreach (WModel item in e.OldItems)
            {
                //Removed items
                item.PropertyChanged -= WPropertyChanged;
            }
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach (WModel item in e.NewItems)
            {
                //Added items
                item.PropertyChanged += WPropertyChanged;
            }
        }
    }


    public void WPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Wd = WSource.Where(x => x.IsD).Count();
    }
```

Where `Wd` is an int

I want the WPropertyChanged function to be called when I replace an item in the observable collection...

I have tried doing `someitemInOC.UpdateAllParameters()` but nothing happens

```
someitemInOC = newListItem;
someitemInOC.UpdateAllParameters();
```

The NotifyPropertyChanged(string.Empty) is called but this has no effect on anything... i don't see the setters get hit or the Notify functions get called...

**Got it working...**

Had to add this to the CollectionChanged function *cry*

```
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
        {
            foreach (WModel item in e.OldItems)
            {
                //Removed items
                item.PropertyChanged -= WPropertyChanged;
            }
            foreach (WModel item in e.NewItems)
            {
                //Added items
                item.PropertyChanged += WPropertyChanged;
            }
        }
```

My life...

Comment: Better to have a viewmodel as for propertychanged have a look at fastDeepCloner it will make your life much easier

Comment: That didn't work for me :-( I'll post more code to show what I mean

Comment: Made some changes @Clemens

Comment: Yep... see update again...

Comment: Got it working....